# Refactoring - a code that puts the arrayList value of an entity that is similar or not the same

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, refactoring

Currently, the application is being developed by utilizing `Spring Boot 2.2`.

The part I'm curious about refactoring is located on the user entity.

User entities receive favorite jobs and genres from users.

This genre and job consist of user entity and `1:N` structure with each entity, and multiple choices are possible without duplication.

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String userName;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private List<Job> likeJobs = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private List<Genre> likeGenres = new ArrayList<>();
     
    ...
```

For example, genres include 'Hip-hop, Pop, K-POP' and jobs such as 'Drummer, DJ, Beatmaker, and Singer'.

Genre and job structure itself can be considered the same.

Therefore, there are many duplicate codes as below.

```java
public void addJobs(Job job){
        this.likeJobs.add(job);
        List<Job> jobsWithoutDuplicates = removeDuplicateFromJobs(this.likeJobs);
        this.likeJobs.clear();
        this.likeJobs.addAll(jobsWithoutDuplicates);
    }

    public void addJobs(List<Job> jobs){
        this.likeJobs.addAll(jobs);
        List<Job> jobsWithoutDuplicates = removeDuplicateFromJobs(this.likeJobs);
        this.likeJobs.clear();
        this.likeJobs.addAll(jobsWithoutDuplicates);
    }

    public void addGenres(Genre genre){
        this.likeGenres.add(genre);
        List<Genre> genresWithoutDuplicates = removeDuplicateFromGenres(this.likeGenres);
        this.likeGenres.clear();
        this.likeGenres.addAll(genresWithoutDuplicates);
    }

    public void addGenres(List<Genre> genres){
        this.likeGenres.addAll(genres);
        List<Genre> genresWithoutDuplicates = removeDuplicateFromGenres(this.likeGenres);
        this.likeGenres.clear();
        this.likeGenres.addAll(genresWithoutDuplicates);
    }

    public List<Job> removeDuplicateFromJobs(List<Job> jobs){
        return jobs.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public List<Genre> removeDuplicateFromGenres(List<Genre> genres){
        return genres.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

I think I can definitely refact this but I don't know what to do.

1. The refactored code must be type-safe.
2. The refactored code must be threaded safe.
3. Do not malfunction after refactoring.

Given the conditions, is there any way to do a good refactoring without violating OOP's SOLID principle?

The first way I did it was the generic type.
I created `addJobsOrGenres(List<?> JobsOrGenres)`.

Then i created an additional method called `isInstanceOf()`.

Through the above two methods, both job and genre objects processed methods that enter the whatever, but I don't know if this is a beautiful refactoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment; adding as an answer.

1. If your `addXXX` methods take `Set` instead of `List`, you can get rid of `removeDuplicateFromXXXX` methods. *Keep in mind proper implementation of `equals` and `hashcode` methods if you go ahead with `Set`.*
2. You can get rid of `addJobs(Job job)`. And let there be `addJobs(Set<Job> jobs)` only. I don't see a harm in that. This way you will have one method to modify in case a pre-processing or post-processing logic comes up in future. Same goes for `addGenres`.

> 1. The refactored code must be type-safe.

When you're doing `List<Job>` or `List<Genere>`, type-safety is taken care of. I wouldn't go with `addJobsOrGenres (List<?> JobsOrGenres)` - one new requirement comes for `job` or `genere`, you start adding more `if-else`s. This makes it more prone to mistake `jobs` for `genere` or vice-versa. Also, see point 2 above about *pre and post processing* as another reason why you shouldn't do this.

> 2. The refactored code must be threaded safe.

Your code does mutation of shared variables, it's not thread safe. You need to add a locking mechanism of some sort. Depending on your use-case (if there are many reads or writes), pick one of the `Lock` strategies.